# C# Linq JSON nested arrays strange behaviour

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I've been trying to create nested arrays with C# Linq JSON library. Is there some reason why first way doesn't work but later one works.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        JObject jo = new JObject();

        // Linq-way
        jo.Add(new JProperty("Nested_failed", new JArray(
            new JArray(
                new JValue(0),
                new JValue(false),
                new JValue(21)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        // Second try
        JArray nested = new JArray();
        nested.Add(new JArray(
            new JValue(0), 
            new JValue(false), 
            new JValue(21)
            )
        );
        jo.Add(new JProperty("Nested_succeed",nested));

        Console.WriteLine(jo.ToString());   
    }
}
```

Results this

```
{
  "Nested_failed": [
    0,
    false,
    21
  ],
  "Nested_succeed": [
    [
      0,
      false,
      21
    ]
  ]
}
```

As far as I can understand, both ways should end up to the same result. But for some reason nested JArray is skipped when you construct it in "Linq-way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes down to the constructors of `JArray'.

```
    // Linq-way
    jo.Add(new JProperty("Nested_failed", new JArray(
        new JArray(
            new JValue(0),
            new JValue(false),
            new JValue(21)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

In your first example above, you are creating a `JArray` from an existing `JArray`. The [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_1.htm) provides the following signature for the constructor that is being chosen in this case:

```
public JArray(JArray other)
```

And of `other`, states:

> A JArray object to copy from.

So this creates a new `JArray` as a copy of an existing one. It doesn't create a nested array.

There are [other constructors](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) on `JArray` that do create a new one (`JArray(Object content)` and `JArray(params Object[] content)`), so you could force your code to use the second constructor I mentioned above by adding a cast to `(object)`:

```
    // Linq-way
    jo.Add(new JProperty("Nested_failed", new JArray(
        (object)new JArray(
            new JValue(0),
            new JValue(false),
            new JValue(21)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! I put this as a accepted answer since you posted it a bit earlier. This is so obvious now. Spent for hours wondering why my code didn't work as expected last night.

Answer (score 3):

You should update the failed part a little bit and pass nested `JArray` to collection initializer of outer `JArray`

```cs
jo.Add(new JProperty("Nested_failed", 
    new JArray
    {
        new JArray(new JValue(0), new JValue(false), new JValue(21))
    }
));
```

[`JArray` ctor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_1.htm) accept a parameter, which is used to copy values from, not for adding it as a nested value

> Initializes a new instance of the `JArray` class from another `JArray`
>   object.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> other
>
> Type: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`
>
> A `JArray` object to copy from.

After adding an collection initializer you'll get the following output, which is the same with the second try

```
  "Nested_failed": [
    [
      0,
      false,
      21
    ]
  ],
  "Nested_succeed": [
    [
      0,
      false,
      21
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course... why didn't I think of using the [collection initializer pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)? Oh well 

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head to a wall quite a while with this one, but now it seems so obvious.